# Magento 500 Internal Server - No Log Files?

Tags: magento, permissions, upgrade, internal-server-error

I have just upgraded my site from Magento 1.7 to 1.9 and i'm now getting a 500 Internal Server Error. From other posts, I have done the following:

- Deleted the maintenance.flag file
- Changed permission on index.php to 755
- Changed permission on downloader/index.php to 755
- Changed permissions recursively on /var to 777
- I've also gone through the files and all directories seem to be 755 and all main files '666'.

I'm still getting the 500 Internal Server Error. The bigger problem is that I have no error files in /log to be able to identify the problem. I created the folder /log (because it didn't exist) but no files are in there. I do not have access to the frontend of backend (because of the 500 Internal Server Error) to make sure that logging is turned on.

Any idea how I can try to troubleshoot / get these error logs?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the 500 Internal Server Error a styled Magento page, or a plain unstyled web server page?

Comment: It is a plain, unstyled page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're getting a plain, un-styled 500 Internal Server Error page, which means its your web server that's returning the error.  This means any error logging is likely to be in your web server log files, and not PHP or Magento's log files.

You'll need to check with your system administrator to find out

1. What web server you're running
2. Where it's log files are
3. And if you have access to those log files

Common places these files might be are

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
/var/log/nginx/...
```

However, every distribution keeps them in a different place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just ran the error from my server actually. This is what I got:

[Thu Oct 12 17:12:29 2017] [warn] [client 207.241.229.48] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds, referer: https://www.ivcatalina.com/
[Thu Oct 12 17:12:29 2017] [error] [client 207.241.229.48] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://www.ivcatalina.com/
[Thu Oct 12 17:13:25 2017] [warn] [client 47.144.197.63] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
[Thu Oct 12 17:13:25 2017] [error] [client 47.144.197.63] Premature end of script headers: index.php

Comment: Every now and then I get an error that there's too many connects to the MySQL and I have to reboot the server. Could the premature script headers and this possibly be related, do you think?

Comment: I am also running 3.5 of MySQL - this could very well be the problem since it requires higher

Comment: Thx Alan Storm, the error was indeed logged in the error log of my virtual host at /var/log/apache2/...